# Cannot set the value of a local variable for a method that is not at the top of the stack

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-debugging

```
 Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim ra As Integer

    sqlconn.Open()
    myCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile(OE_Category,OE_SubCategory,OE_ID,OE_Name,OE_User,OE_Brand,OE_Model,OE_Specs,OE_SerialNo,OE_PropertyNo,OE_MacAddress,OE_Static_IP,OE_Vendor,OE_PurchaseDate,OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear,OE_WarrantyStatus,OE_Status,OE_Dept_Code,OE_Location_Code,OE_Remarks) VALUES('" + cmbCategory.Text + "','" + cmbSubCategory.Text + "','" + txtOEID.Text + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtUser.Text + "','" + cmbBrand.Text + "','" + cmbModel.Text + "','" + txtSpecs.Text + "','" + txtSerialNo.Text + "','" + txtPropertyNo.Text + "','" + txtStaticIp.Text + "','" + txtVendor.Text + "','" + txtPurchaseDate.Text + "','" + cmbWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text + "','" + txtStatus.Text + "','" + cmbDeptCode.Text + "','" + cmbLocationCode.Text + "','" + cmbRemarks.Text + "')", sqlconn)
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("New Row Inserted" & ra)
    sqlconn.Close()
```

edited this is my whole code for the add button

Comment: Would suggest you do some reading on "SQL Injection".

Comment: [Cannot set the value of a local variable for a method that is not at the top of the stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h67etbsc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  `You can only modify variables if they are the top of the call stack. For example, if procedure1 calls procedure2 and you are in procedure1, you cannot modify variables in procedure2.`  And this has nothing to do with SQL or TextBoxes or anything other than debugging.

Comment: Something tells me that you are not showing all the code that involves these variables

Comment: I presume you use the variable `ra` to show how many rows were inserted. You dont need that because your `INSERT Statement` is set to insert only 1 row.

Comment: @Steve thats all my code to add records to sql server sir

Comment: @Ruben even though i comment the code ra it returns error to myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Of course that is not all of your code. Where is the declaration of sqlConn, and the connection string used? In which method do you have this code? (You have written a method rigth?)

Comment: @Steve i edited the code. i showed it all now